# Are fortran library required if using only modules?

Tags: module, fortran, shared-libraries

I'm trying to clean up a fortran `make` process for distribution. Currently, two libraries are made, and then the executable is compiled linking to the libraries and including the module files. I see from previous answers ([Distribute compiled fortran library with module files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700315/distribute-compiled-fortran-library-with-module-files)) that you can't get rid of the module files and that they can be different for every machine and compiler. This is very annoying.

However, the code in my libraries are made up entirely of modules. It seems like I don't need the library part at all; I can just include the modules. I've tried this and it does compile and run on small examples.

Will this always work (when all I have are modules in the libraries)? Is it best practice? Should I instead consider rewriting my libraries NOT to use modules so I can avoid all these compiler dependencies and only distribute the lib*.a files? Is that what [this document](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1601-N1650/N1602.pdf) is referring to by using submodules (which no one supports [static lib with many modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081846/static-lib-with-many-modules))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It really depends on the features you have in your library. Does it have only a couple of declarations? Then the `.mod` files would suffice, but why not distribute the source in such a simple case?

Are all your public procedures simple enough, so that they do not require an explicit interface and they are outside of modules? Then you don't need any `.mod` files.

Do you have a simple public module or an include file with the public API and the rest is private? You can then distribute the source of the API module or the include file. I would recommend to place just the interface blocks and other declarations in this module.

Be aware of one important problem. You can get away (using interface locks or similar) with avoiding the non-portable `.mod` files, but if the procedures are using some more advanced argument passing, their ABI is often NOT portable between different compilers or even some compiler versions. You would the be able to compile it and get mysterious crashes when calling your library.

Submodules can change it all, but actually I do not expect they will solve portability between compilers. The user of your library will still need the same compiler you had. It is true that interfacing the closed source software will be easier, but not more portable between compilers.

Comment: This code is all in modules - there are no external declarations. There are perhaps 20 files with 30 or more modules defining at least that many derived types and many more procedures. The user's `PROGRAM` ends up pretty much being a script file `USE`ing and calling these modules.

Comment: There is still some misunderstanding. If you write "However, the code in my libraries are made up entirely of modules. It seems like I don't need the library part at all; I can just include the modules." What is "include modules?" What is "library part"? You need some file with the compiled code, an object file (.o .obj) or a library (.so .a .dll). You can get away with .mod only when there are only declarations and no executable code in the modules.

Comment: If you mean by "only modules" that just the `.f90` source files can be enough, then yes of course, you do not have to build a separate library, you can just call `f90 library.f90 main.f90` and have the result, but I believe this is quite obvious.

Comment: I'm sorry about the poor CS vocabulary confusing things. So the library archive replaces the object files but not the ".mod" compiled module files. That is now clear. In your original post, are you suggesting to distribute a library archive and a module source file where I define all the interfaces? Are there examples of that floating around?

Comment: Is the library closed source or open source?

Comment: I distribute the current version open source.  I am exploring the idea of using a closed library for the new version, since it will be used commercially.

Comment: The whole problem concerns mostly the closed source solutions. If you want to protect the source code, you can compile the library, whatever internal structure it has, and leave couple of (possibly external) API subroutines, to which you publish a source file with interfaces. This interface file can include a module.

Answer (score 0):

You can link either from a library lib*.a, or from object files.  Both will be at least platform dependent and so more difficult to distribute than source code.  library file might have the advantage of fewer files.  In either case, linking from lib*a or object files, you can present your code to the user as a library of procedures to call.  If you don't want to distribute your source code, then you will have to compile for however many platforms you support.  Modules are a major advantage of modern Fortran, automating the checking of procedure actual and dummy arguments.  Compared to, for example, C header files, they have the advantage of being automatic, but the disadvantage of producing a compiler-dependent intermediate file. If you are providing procedures to other programmers, it would seem a bad idea not to provide them with this interface checking.   If you want to hide your source code, then you could write interface blocks describing the procedures and distribute only this source for them to compile.